# How can I determine the alloy in a Peltier module?

Tags: peltier

Simple question, I know I have the following Peltier module : [12711-5L31-03CL](http://www.customthermoelectric.com/tecs/pdf/12711-5L31-03CL_spec_sht.pdf). I have it's datasheet.

I'd be interested in knowing its alloy so I can know it's Seebeck coefficient and thermal coefficient. I cannot find what its alloy is. Is there somewhere else than the datasheet where I could find it? On the site of the company, I can't find it either.

Comment: 1. Can you provide a link to the datasheet?
2. What is "alliage"? I don't think this is a term normally used in English. Can you give a formula for alliage in terms of other parameters so we can figure out what's the usual English term?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!! : Here is the link to the datasheet : http://www.customthermoelectric.com/tecs/pdf/12711-5L31-03CL_spec_sht.pdf

Comment: for the alliage, I meant the conductor between the ceramic substrate (p-n junction)

Comment: Does the word alliage appear in that datasheet?

Comment: about that, sorry it's a french term that I though existed in english. I just mean the conductor between the ceramic plates. I don't see it in the datasheet

Comment: I'm sure the manufacturers know how to use one of those  [newfangled telephone things](http://i.stack.imgur.com/36Xkf.jpg).

Comment: tried that one without success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked a similar question yesterday about finding the Seebeck coefficient. In that question you gave the following equation:

$$V = aT + RI$$

Now look at this graph you just provided:

[image]

If you can make one assumption about the device, namely that its resistance doesn't change significantly as the temperature delta increases then you can relatively easily figure out the Seebeck coefficient.

Assuming the resistance doesn't change and the current is held constant the change in voltage is entirely due to the change in temperature, which you know from the graph, and the Seebeck coefficient.

For instance, at zero degrees temperature delta the voltage total is about 2.0V. Because the Seebeck term is cancelled, due to the temperature delta being zero, RI is about 2.0V (given a current around 0.45 amps). If you draw a straight line up from that, meaning *RI does not change*, with a temperature delta of 40°C (313.15 Kelvin) the voltage total is right about 3.9V.

With a little math we can solve the rest:

$$3.9[V] = a[V/K]*313.15[K] + 2.0[V]$$

What does a, the Seebeck coefficient, equal? 6067!? Seems high right? Look in the upper corner of the graph, this device has 127 couples stacked on top of eachother. So divide the result to get the coefficient per couple.

$$6067\div127 \approx 47$$

Which material has the Seebeck coefficient of around 47? [Antimony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_coefficient#Seebeck_coefficients_for_some_common_materials). Though it's not likely it's made of pure antimony. But you were just looking for the Seebeck coefficient anyway, so that xy problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

I think the word you want is "alloy". Unfortunately it's not likely to be well specified.

The two materials forming the TE junction are just differently doped semiconductor. This creates two problems if you want to know exactly what alloys are involved:

1. The junction is not abrupt. The alloy changes somewhat gradually between the p and n region. There's no two single numbers that define the alloys. There's a profile of alloy vs. position that might vary from device to device.
2. The doping is probably not extremely precisely controlled. The dopant concentration might only be controlled to within a factor of 10.

So the manufacturer is not even going to know the alloy exactly. They are just going to know that across their manufacturing tolerances, they can achieve the performance specified on the datasheet.

Comment: Photon,  I found your answer a bit confusing.  A TEC has alternating pieces of n and p type semiconductor.  (such that the direction of motion of the charge carriers in each material is in the same direction... from hot to cold (or cold to hot).  There is no junction so to say.. except at the conductors top and bottom.  I'm not sure but my understanding was that most room temperature TEC's are Bismuth Telluride.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_materials#Bismuth_chalcogenides_and_their_nanostructures  I assume you know this, but maybe you could make your answer less confusing.